# Scene disappears when I set origin in camera tracking

Tags: camera, tracking, scene

I have a video that I applied camera tracking to, i.e. added the markers and solved. I get a nice solve error of 0.22. The I try to set origin to the scene. The camera then completely disappears and by the looks of it, it has moved outside the sphere that is the blender world. The same happens when I try to set the floor, without setting the origin. When I finally set up the tracking scene, nothing shows within camera view. I change to top view and I can see the cube and plane are there.
[image]
This is the situation before I pick a marker and press set origin: enter image description here The cube and the plane are visible from the camera just the way I need them to be as I am going to substitute them with my model. But to improve the tracking, as, if I play it as is, it is very jerky and the 3d objects do not follow the camera properly, I pick the selected marker and press set origin.

The following is the result:
[image]

The models completely disappear. Obviously that beats the whole point of camera tracking if the 3d models are invisible.

I know they have not been removed from the scene as if I go into top view or any of the orthographic views, they are still visible. It is only in camera view that they are not visible.

What I would like to know is why does setting the origin on camera tracking move the camera so far out that the scene is no longer visible. And is there a way of controlling the camera's distance from the origin when doing camera tracking?

P.S. I am such a newbie at this that I am not even sure what details are needed to answer my question. Please advise, so I can be clearer where possible. Here is a screenshot of the outliner with the camera selected:
[image]

Comment: The camera has clipping planes set, I can't see the scale of your scene in your screen shot, but perhaps the camera is just moving too far away and all the objects are being clipped?

Comment: That's the thing. The camera is just moving too far away and I do not know the reason why. That is what I am asking. Why does the camera move so far away? (As for the scale, I never modified it, so I am guessing it is the default.)

Comment: Ok. I played around with the camera clipping like you suggested, as well as the scale of the object, and everything was sorted out. Thank you.